# Swtich from local branch to remote branch without mess up the GIT repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, branching-and-merging, smartgit

I have a project on Bitbucket, since others developers works on the same project too I decide to go with `branch` in order to maintain `develop` branch as clean as possible and let developers play without mess up the entire repository. I created a `Local Branch` at office as image show:

[image]

I tough this isn't right since,. perhaps, I'm not able to access that branch from home to continue working on that branch. In that case which will be the right way to move the worked code to Bitbucket branch with the same name and same code. Any advice?

PS: I'm using Smartgit/HG as client

**Update: hit Push To (CTRL+SHIFT+U)**

I did a right click under `CommonBundle-dev` at `LocalBranches` and get this:

[image]

Should I "push" or not? I'm afraid to let the repository unusable or mess up others work

**Update: how to merge from *any* branch to develop?**

I have another question regarding this, see the image above:

[image]

How I can merge my branch changes to `develop` branch?

Comment: You created it on your local git repo but did you push it to the remote?

Comment: @fge I don't think so, how I push to remote? If I push to remote it will create a branch on remote or switch to `develop`? See my edit!!

Comment: From the GUI I have no idea at all. I always use git from the command line. If your remote is `origin`, your local branch is `develop` and you want to push it as `mydevelop` then that will be `git push --set-upstream origin develop:mydevelop`.

Comment: `develop`... sounds like the project is using git-flow? In this case, I'd recommend to use SmartGit's Git-Flow integration from the **Branch** menu: first configure, then create a Feature branch for your current HEAD, push that from your office, fetch it from home, working ...

Comment: @mstrap I don't know if we use git-flow and I don't think so but I goes with "fge" solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I "push" or not?

Well, yes. Otherwise you still won't be able to access it from the outside!

> I'm afraid to let the repository unusable or mess up others work

No risks. A git repository has no "files" per se but is a directed acyclic graph of commits; what you do when you add a branch is just create another branch to the graph; it will not affect any other branch.

The difference between the remote and you is that you have the "contents" of a branch "checked out" in a directory; the bitbucket remote doesn't (it is what is called a "bare" repository).